# CSS Graph- Bars not showing correctly

Tags: php, css, csv, graph

I'm trying to create a CSS/HTML based graph using this tutorial [here](http://www.thewojogroup.com/2008/12/css-stacked-bar-graphs/).

However instead of putting the data directly into the html code I'm importing it from a CSV file using PHP with the following code.

```
    <?PHP
/* Open CSV file */

$handle = fopen("defects.csv", "r");
$c = 0;
/* gets data from csv file */
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
/* stores dates as variable $date */
        $date[$c] = $data[0];
  $c++;
  /* inserts defect data into html code */
  echo "<dd class=\"p" . $data[2] . "\"><span><b>" . $data[2] . "</b></span></dd>";
  echo "<dd class=\"sub p" . $data[3] . "\" ><span><b>" . $data[3] . "</b></span></dd>";
}

echo "</dl>";
echo "<ul class=\"xAxis\">";
/* X AXIS */
/* inserts date data into html code for x axis */
for ($d=0; $d < $c; $d++) {
 echo "<li>" . $date[$d] . "</li>";
}
?>
```

The values are being placed correctly on the chart, but the bars aren't appearing. The CSS code I have for the bars is:

```
/* default column styling */  


 dl#csschart span{
  height:50%;
  background:url(../images/barx.png) repeat-y;
  } 


dl#csschart .sub{
 margin-left:-33px;

}
dl#csschart .sub span{
 background:url(../images/subBarx.png) repeat-y;
}
```

Just in case it helps, I've print screened how the graph should look. You can see it at: *http://allured.info/graph/failgraph.png*

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this, the images weren't linked properly and then the darker coloured bar was covering the lighter one.